# android geocoder void getfromlocation how to get addresses?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

i have geocoder class in my android activity which contains google map

i need to reverse the geocode using

```
getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults, Geocoder.GeocodeListener listener)
```

this method has void declaration but must returns list of addresses, according to google they said to do the below

Provides an array of Addresses that attempt to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude. The returned addresses should be localized for the locale provided to this class's constructor.

how to do that to get list of addresses if this method is void type?

Comment: By implementing `Geocoder.GeocodeListener` and passing the instance as the last argument to `getFromLocation`.

Answer (score 8):

**(Kotlin)**

The list of addresses will be available when implementing the abstract method `onGeocode()`. To access the list of addresses you should declare a variable with an implementation for the `GeocodeListener` instance:

```
val geocodeListener = @RequiresApi(33) object : Geocoder.GeocodeListener {
    override fun onGeocode(addresses: MutableList<Address>) {
        // do something with the addresses list
    }
}
```

or using the lambda form:

```
val geocodeListener = Geocoder.GeocodeListener { addresses ->
    // do something with the addresses list
}
```

After that, you call the `getFromLocation()` method on a `Geocoder` instance, surrounding it with an Android SDK check, and providing it the object that you implemented earlier:

```
val geocoder = Geocoder(context, locale)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
    // declare here the geocodeListener, as it requires Android API 33
    geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults, geocodeListener)
} else {
    val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults)
    // For Android SDK < 33, the addresses list will be still obtained from the getFromLocation() method
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I would like to mention, that I had issue with using `Geocoder.GeocodeListener` and Koin - Koin was throwing runtime exception 'class not found Geocoder.GeocodeListener'. Not sure what was the reason of this, but for now just rolled back to using deprecated method. Maybe Koin should fix something.

Comment: That happened because you have presumably run the code on an Android device/ emulator with an SDK level lower than 33 (Android 13) without fully isolating any use of the `Geocoder.GeocodeListener` inside the first branch of the SDK if-check. The new approach is available only for SDK ≥ 33, whilst for the lower levels the deprecated methods remain in use.

Comment: Actually not, for Android < 13 I've used 'old' method.

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
suspend fun getCityStateName(location : Location?) : String? =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine<String?> { cancellableContinuation ->
        location?.let { loc ->
            Geocoder(context).getFromLocation(
                loc.latitude, loc.longitude, 1
            ) { list -> // Geocoder.GeocodeListener
                list.firstOrNull()?.let { address ->
                    cancellableContinuation.resumeWith(
                        Result.success(
                            "${address.locality} ${address.adminArea}"
                            )
                        )
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```